# How is translational symmetry related to Fourier decomposition?

Tags: cosmology, symmetry, fourier-transform, perturbation-theory

The book (The Cosmic Microwave Background By Ruth Durrer) about cosmological perturbations says that because of translational symmetry of the background at a constant time, we can decompose our perturbations into eigenvalues of Laplacian which in flat space turns into the Fourier decomposition of that perturbation.

It also says that because of rotational symmetry of the background, a tensorial quantity can be decomposed into scalar, vector and tensor parts.

Here I can't understand what's the relation between symmetries of the background and the possible decompositions.

Here are the paragraphs quoted from the book:

> Since the {t = constant} hypersurfaces are homogeneous and isotropic,
>   it is reasonable to perform a harmonic analysis: a (spatial) tensor
>   field on these hypersurfaces can be decomposed into components which
>   transform irreducibly under translations and rotations. All such
>   components evolve independently. Decomposition into irreducible
>   components of the translation symmetry corresponds to a harmonic
>   analysis, i.e., decomposition into eigenfunctions of the Laplacian.
>   For a scalar quantity f in the case K = 0 this is nothing else than
>   its Fourier decomposition
>   ...
>   In addition, a tensorial variable (at fixed position x) can be
>   decomposed into irreducible components under the rotation group SO(3).

Comment: The trigonometric function $\exp(i k x)$ is an eigenvector of the translation operator. If you translate $x \rightarrow x + \Delta x$ you get $\exp(i k \Delta x) \exp(i k x)$. Is that enough of a hint?